# Is there conclusive evidence that Rowling planned the existence of the Deathly Hallows before the book of that name?

Tags: harry-potter, jk-rowling, deathly-hallows

I can't find this question previously answered here and as this site is about gathering a database of knowledge, I feel it must be asked.

Inspired by my brief discussion with @Richard.

I believe Rowling has planted nods to them in the books, but is there solid proof out there that she planned the hallows before The Deathly Hallows book?

Comment: She talked about the deathly hallows individually throughout the books, didn't mention how they were linked until the last book. She never used the phrase Deathly Hallows as far as i know.

Comment: That's what I believe, but the matter tends to be debated. Let's get some Stack Exchange proof!

Comment: Do you mean the notion of the Hallows (highly magical objects that together make you the master of Death), or specifically the name _Deathly Hallows_ used to refer to them?

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet - Any evidence in or out of universe that she had definitely planned for them and didn't take some items previously mentioned and add back story.

Comment: Ah so it was a duplicate. The answers in the original are quite brief, which is a shame, but I'm not sure how to rewrite to go deeper. May do at some point.